# Cookies while using Node

Tags: node.js, express

Currently working on a small chat like system. I am trying to save the username of a user whenever they enter it. I figured the best option would be to use cookies. So far I have tried a few things and failed. Below is some of the code that I have tried using(didn't work). Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated. Right now I am just trying to save a cookie and it isn't working for some reason. Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');

var app = express();

var incomingMessage;

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(expressSession({secret:'somesecrettokenhere', saveUnititialized: true, resave: true}));


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.cookie('name', 'express').send('cookie set');
});
```

I have tried to console.log(document.cookie); and it does not return what I tried setting for some reason.

Comment: Chat systems are better built on web sockets with a stated connection. This means you can save the username in a js object and handle it at will on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will look into it.